# writing the data into local modal in angular-xeditable

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

In my case i am using http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table for editing entire table , If table is having two or more rows and click on edit and i updated some values (text values) , on click event i want get those updated values in controller. can you please advise.
http://jsfiddle.net/0amredgj/3/

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);
 app.run(function(editableOptions) {
     editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.user = {
name: 'awesome user',
   name2: 'awesome222 user',
   name3: 'awesome user',
   name4: 'awesome222 user'
};

 $scope.result = function(data){
 alert($scope.user.name)
  alert($scope.user.name2)
   alert($scope.user.name3)
    alert($scope.user.name4)
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

```
<input ... e-name="username">
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/2fqtv8yp/)